# Можно ли применить слово "щегольской" к городу?

Tags: стилистика

Имея в виду город высоких цен, город богатых и для богатых. Синоним - роскошный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну если [САМ Лотман](https://www.spb.kp.ru/daily/26815.4/3851115/)...

> Теперь же настало время познакомиться с другим Петербургом – парадным.
>   Или, как писал знаменитый пушкиновед Юрий Михайлович Лотман об
>   онегинском городе на Неве, «аристократическим и щегольским».

то таки да.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавка - из Гуглокниг:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]